# Auth with multiple firebase realtime databases on web not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two Firebase realtime databases. I have managed to connect, read, and write to both of them from my web-based client. However, I am going back through my security rules and made it so you can only read/write if you are authenticated using

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null" ,
    ".write": "auth.uid != null" 
  }
```

However, for some reason I am now unable to connect to the database, it says that permission is denied. I am authenticated on the client using Google, and everything else with auth works as expected. For example, I'm able to print out the user's uid and everything. Here's the client side code I have (censored).

```
  var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "------------------",
authDomain: "-------------",
databaseURL: "-------------",
projectId: "-------",
};
// Initialize Firebase
var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'app2');

firebase.database(app).ref('boards').child(boardID).once('value', function(snapshot) {//I do stuff here})
```

Error:

```
Error: permission_denied at /boards/id: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at util.ts:526
    at onComplete (SyncTree.ts:651)
    at Object.onComplete (Repo.ts:167)
    at PersistentConnection.ts:247
    at si.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.ts:554)
    at ei.onDataMessage_ (Connection.ts:317)
    at ei.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (Connection.ts:309)
    at $r.onMessage (Connection.ts:205)
    at $r.appendFrame_ (WebSocketConnection.ts:273)
    at $r.handleIncomingFrame (WebSocketConnection.ts:326)
```

And these are the firebase scripts I'm using

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Is this a known bug? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by switching from

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

to

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

And removing the `, 'app2)` from `var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'app2');`

This made the second database be the default database and now everything is working properly. However, if there is ever a time where both database references are required on the client, this will once again become a problem, and as far as I can tell cannot be fixed unless the Firebase developers release a patch.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication restores the user's authentication state when you reload the page. This requires a call to the server, which happens asynchronously. Most likely the authentication check hasn't finished yet when you attach the listener.

To fix this, always attach listeners that require authentication in [an `onAuthStateChanged` callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
// Initialize Firebase
var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'app2');

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    firebase.database(app).ref('boards').child(boardID).once('value', function(snapshot) {//I do stuff here})
  }
}
```

---

If you ever have similar problems again, I recommend logging the active user's UID to help in troubleshooting:

```
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser ? firebase.auth().currentUser.uid : "No user");
firebase.database(app).ref('boards').child(boardID).once('value', function(snapshot) {//I do stuff here})
```

This will often make it immediately obvious why the security rules are rejecting your write.

Comment: I'm still getting a permission denied error. I placed the read request inside an authsstatechanged listener, and print out the uid and the rest of the user's info, and sure enough all the information is there. I also played with the rules so now you can only read if you AREN'T authenticated, and it works. So for some reason the uid is not being sent along with the read request. Should I change something inside the firebaseConfig?

Comment: That's extremely uncommon. Do you think you can set up a reproduction on a site like jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: I'm sorry for how messy the code is. I've kinda been scrambling to get this error fixed. But here's the code. https://jsfiddle.net/t8hLdkv0/

Comment: When I load that fiddle, it shows `firebase is not defined` in the JavaScript console. The idea is that you reproduce the `permission denied` problem on a site where I can look at it, which is the fastest way to help you with what seems to be an unusual situation.

Comment: This issue can be easily reproduced by making a second database and trying to read from it while it is under the same security rules. I'm not allowed to share anything about the database, which includes giving away the populated firebaseConfig JSON. I managed to fix my own problem which I have posted above, but if possible (because I see you work for Firebase) please do look into this. Thank you for your help!